# Ad two bindings to web.config

Tags: iis, web-config

I am trying to enable an application that will work with two bindings.
Since I am going to distribute it to clients, some will have IIS that is open for HTTP and HTTPS and some might have only one of them. 
I am not able to complete this task of providing access on HTTP and HTTPS according to the configurations of the IIS. 
This is my web.config:

```
<system.serviceModel>
    <services>
        <service behaviorConfiguration="RoutingBehavior" name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService">
            <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehaviorHTTPS" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicSSL" name="RouterEndpoint" contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" >
            </endpoint>
            <endpoint address="http://" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Basic" name="RouterEndpoint" contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" >
            </endpoint>
        </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
        <serviceBehaviors>
            <behavior name="RoutingBehavior">
                <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
                <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
            </behavior>
        </serviceBehaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
            <behavior name="WebBehaviorHTTPS">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
            <behavior name="WebBehavior">
                <webHttp/>
            </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="Basic" receiveTimeout="02:30:00" sendTimeout="02:30:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicSSL" receiveTimeout="02:30:00" sendTimeout="02:30:00" maxBufferSize="2147483647" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
                <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="2147483647" maxArrayLength="2147483647" />
                <security mode="Transport">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                </security>
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="False" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="True">
        <serviceActivations>
            <add relativeAddress="EZRouterService.svc" service="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService, System.ServiceModel.Routing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" factory="Equivio.Zoom.Web.EZRouterServiceFactory"/>
        </serviceActivations>
    </serviceHostingEnvironment>
</system.serviceModel>
```

Edit: When accessing the application the first binding is used (first as the one the come first on the list above). When I switch to an HTTP environment I am not able to access.

When debugging I get the following exception:

*Additional information: Could not find a base address that matches scheme http for the endpoint with binding BasicHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [https].*

Comment: Please explain what "not able to complete the task" means

Comment: When accessing the application the first binding is used (first as the one the come first on the list above). When I switch to an HTTP environment I am not able to access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest giving both service endpoint a unique NAME value, and set them use same ADDRESS since they already have different bindingConfiguration and behaviorConfiguration.

```
<services>
    <service behaviorConfiguration="RoutingBehavior" name="System.ServiceModel.Routing.RoutingService">
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehaviorHTTPS" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicSSL" name="RouterEndpointSSL" contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" >
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="" behaviorConfiguration="WebBehavior" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="Basic" name="RouterEndpointBasic" contract="System.ServiceModel.Routing.IRequestReplyRouter" >
        </endpoint>
    </service>
</services>
```

I believe with your current relativeAddress="EZRouterService.svc"  and endpoint address="http://"  , since the value was not a full address, that the URI one would have needed to use for http was http://{baseadress}/EZRouterService.svc/http://  potentially causing some confusion.

Comment: Thank you. I know this comment came after a while but it worked.